# Lightswitch cascading dropdown list

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I would like to create a search screen in lightswitch silverlight. I need to have 2 dropdown lists one is to search the states and the other is regions based on the state selected. It will then bring back the employees that belong to the state. I have the following tables Employees, States, Regions and EmployeesinRegions. Currently my search screen brings back all the employees in the system. I am still new to Lightswitch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make the cascading drop down lists:

1. Make a query in the Regions Table. Add a filter for State Id with a parameter (Where State.Id = [@] StateId). Don't forget to name it (e.g. RegionsByState)
2. In your screen (Employees screen) add Data Item -> Choose Query -> Select States (if not already added)
3. again add Data Item -> Choose Query -> Select (RegionsByState)
4. In the Query Parameters select your parameter (StateId), in properties fill the Parameter Binding (should be something like: States.SelectedItem.Id)
5. If you already have the drop down lists in the screen then all you need is to change "Choices" property of the drop down list and choose the added query (States and RegionsByState)
6. To add the drop downs : Add Data Item -> Property -> Choose State. Uncheck Required.
7. Same as 5 -> Choose Region. don't forget to name it
8. Add your your new properties to the screen.

Now you have the cascading drop down lists (I think they are Auto Complete Boxes actually) anyways, to filter Employees by State and/or Region just redo steps 1 to 5 (With some minor changes)